# What is the meaning of template arguments of this type - `ClassA<T> T::*ELEM`?

Tags: c++, templates, member-pointers, intrusive-containers

I came across this code recently, in the context of intrusive lists:

```
template<typename T> struct Node{
    T *next;
    T *prev;
    Node(): next(nullptr), prev(nullptr){}
};


/*
 * Intrusive doubly-linked-list
 *
 * */
template<typename T, Node<T> T::*NODE>
class List{
T *head;
T *tail;
public: 
    List():head(nullptr), tail(nullptr){}
    ~List() {clear();}

    /*
    * Add an element at the head of list
    * @param elem item to be inserted
    * */
    void add_to_front(T *elem){

        Node<T> *node = &(elem->*NODE);

        assert((node->next) == nullptr);
        assert((node->prev) == nullptr);

        node->next = head;

        if(head != nullptr){
            Node<T> *temp = &(head->*NODE);
            temp->prev = elem;
        }

        head = elem;

        if(tail == nullptr)
            tail = head;

    }
    //other member functions ,etc.
    ..
    ..
};
```

I see similar code in the boost [intrusive list library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/intrusive/list.html) (`member_hook<class T, class Hook, Hook T::* PtrToMember>`).

My question is regarding the template argument `Node<T> T::*NODE`. I am not an expert in C++, but I have never come across this particular syntax before, and don't know what to search for to understand it.

What does it mean? What is its purpose, and what should I interpret it as - "**NODE is a pointer to a Node, belonging to T**"? That doesn't make sense to me, because T isn't known to contain specific members ahead of time, and as far as I know, `::` is used to resolve scope.

As well, if someone could clarify the use of `*NODE` in this line, for instance : `Node<T> *node = &(elem->*NODE);`, that would help me understand what this is being used for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a member pointer. `NODE` is a pointer to a member of `T` that has type `Node<T>`.

Similarly, `foo->*bar` is shorthand for `(*foo).*bar` where `.*` is the dereference-pointer-to-member operator. `elem->*NODE` accesses the member of `*elem` pointed to by `NODE`.

Comment: is it then expected for T to have a member of type Node<T>?

Comment: @aspen100 Yes, that's the intrusive bit. To be usable as a `List` element, `T` must contain a `Node<T>` member somewhere. The location of this member is specified by the `NODE` member pointer.

Answer (score 1):

That's called "pointer to member operator".

The standard (N3690, section 5.5) says:

The pointer-to-member operators ->* and .* group left-to-right.

The binary operator .* binds its second operand, which shall be of type “pointer to member of T” to its first operand, which shall be of class T or of a class of which T is an unambiguous and accessible base class.
The result is an object or a function of the type specified by the second operand.

The binary operator ->* binds its second operand, which shall be of type “pointer to member of T” to its first operand, which shall be of type “pointer to T” or “pointer to a class of which T is an unambiguous and accessible base class.” The expression E1->*E2 is converted into the equivalent form (*(E1)).*E2.

Also have a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access.

The operator ::* is the same -- accessing using class name instead of a variable, much like when you have class C and object obj you can either do C::func or obj.func or (&obj)->func.